# Display Unit Test results in an ASP.NET MVC5 view

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I am building an internal business suite on ASP.NET MVC 5 and would like to have a developer-accessible page where I can click a button and run all (or a subset of all) the unit tests defined in the application. It should then return the results of the run in a way that my non-technically literate superiors can understand.

Every time I search for solutions, the results assume I am asking about testing my views or controllers, which is NOT what I am trying to do. I am trying to write a view whose controller can find, iterate through, and return the results of all the unit tests in the assembly.

I am using 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Comment: In the controller, execute test suit(command line commands), usually test runners will create output result(.xml file for example), open this file and convert test results to the view you want to display.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks I was hoping to do something like that. The part I need clarification in is executing the test suite from the controller. I don't know the commands to do this. Can you expand on that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx